# Bin packing : item to be packed in a certain bin depend on previously packed items to that bin.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, integer-programming, np-complete

I am working on an engineering problem. I need to implement an algorithm that looks like a certain variant of bin packing. **Specifically,  in this variant of the bin packing, the size of a certain item i to be packed in bin j is a function of already packed items in the bin j.** Does that variant of the bin packing exist/studied in the literature already? its name? Otherwise do you think that this problem better fits another well known algorithm studied in the literature.

Thank you.

Comment: So the size of item $i$ in bin $b$ depends on *all* the other items in bin $b?$

Comment: Yes, any idea on wether this variant of the bin packing studied already? Thanks.

Comment: You can start with **submodular bin packing problem**, in which the space used in each bin is not equal to the sum of the allocated items, but it is a certain submodular function of it. See, e.g., this paper and references therein: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2192440623000187